# What does a Slurm job have to do with ssh?

Tags: ssh, slurm

I am trying to run my first Slurm job.  It is hanging right after the executable begins running.  I get the error

```
Could not create directory '/p/home/mydir/.ssh'.
Could not create directory '/p/home/mydir/.ssh'.
Could not create directory '/p/home/mydir/.ssh'.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
```

I do have a `.ssh` directory in my home space.  Neither my script nor my executable make any reference whatsoever to ssh.  Is there some kind of ssh setup I need to do before Slurm will run (like making keys)?  Our sys admins haven't documented anything like and I can't find it on the web anywhere.